# Why does my VBScript file fail when I run it from the command line?

Tags: command-line, vbscript, itunes

I have a very simple VBScript file that interacts with iTunes via a COM object:

If I double-click on the .vbs file, it works fine. But if I run it from the command line, it fails:

```
c:\windows\SysWOW64\wscript myscript.vbs
```

iTunes opens, but the commands don't work, and after a short delay I get this:

```
ActiveX component can't create object: 'iTunes.Application'
Code: 800A01AD
```

The problem remains when I use `cscript`, and when I use the system32 version.

So, two questions:

1. Why is the behaviour different when double-clicking/running from the CLI?
2. How do I fix it, so it runs from the CLI, too?

Edited to add script:

```
Dim oiTunes, oTracks, oAdd
Set oiTunes = CreateObject("iTunes.Application")
Set oTracks = oiTunes.LibraryPlaylist
Set oAdd = oTracks.AddFile("D:\Users\Mark\Music\Downloaded iPlayer\Temp\temp.mp4")
Do : Loop While oAdd.InProgress = True
Set oAdd = Nothing
Set oTracks = Nothing
Set oiTunes = Nothing
```

Comment: This [MS support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/194801) might help. It mentions ASP, but the issue is the same.

Comment: I'm aware of the information in that article, but I'm not sure it's relevant. The fact that the script works when double-clicking would suggest the files aren't missing. So it's likely to be a permissions problem. But what permissions do I need to set for the command line?

Comment: Can you show how you are loading the object in your script?

Comment: @Damien - I've added the script to the question.

Comment: Interesting, have you tried the old "wscript -regserver" trick? I'll go try the same script on a win7 machine and advise.. Have you tried your script on any other machines? You don't have some AV program interfering do you? Although, you'd expect both to produce the same results..

Comment: If it is any consolation - it works 100% fine on a Windows 7 machine via cmd prompt... :( What version of iTunes are you running out of curiosity..?

Comment: It really sounds like a 32bit script trying to open a 64bit com / vice versa..... Are you sure you're not trying to do that...?

Comment: @Damien I suspected that at first as well, but a quick check revealed that on a 64-bit system a double-click on a `.vbs` file actually launches the script with the 32-bit `wscript.exe`.

Comment: @Damien/ `wscript -regserver` doesn't help. Specifying 32/64-bit doesn't help.

In case it's relevant, the event log says:
`The server {DC0C2640-1415-4644-875C-6F4D769839BA} did not register with DCOM within the required timeout.`

Comment: I know this may seem extreme  but you sound like you might be one of those regcleaner types (no offence:)) - have you tried reinstalling itunes or at least initiating a repair? Sounds like one of those CLSIDs might be corrupted (or in conflict with something else you may have installed). Sorry we're not being overly helpful here! :(

Comment: @Damien. Would you believe repairing iTunes fixed the problem? Thank you. If you'd like to add that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Out of curiosity do you run Media Monkey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script you have shared works fine for me. Perhaps one of the CSLIDs has become corrupt - try reinstalling or repairing iTunes.

Comment: Unfortunately, opening the command prompt as administrator, and/or disabling UAC doesn't help. Exactly the same thing occurs. I'm using Windows 8.1, by the way.

Comment: Modified answer based on our efforts - we got there in the end! Well done Mark!